# remove tag and add additional css class to data-sly-resource

Tags: aem, sightly

Here's my code and I want to add another css class `toggleable-content` to the existing code:

```
  <sly data-sly-resource="${'item' @ resourceType='components/header'}"></sly>
```

This code would look something like this:

```
<section aria-label="aria label">
   <ul class="row">
      <li class="col">
            <div class="body px-3">
               <h2 class="h3">
                  body
               </h2>
               <p>body text</p>
            </div>
      </li>
   </ul>
</section>
```

I want to remove `section` tag and add another css class `toggleable-content` to the `<ul>` tag. Below is what I'd like to achieve:

```
       <ul class="row toggleable-content">
          <li class="col">
                <div class="body px-3">
                   <h2 class="h3">
                      body
                   </h2>
                   <p>body text</p>
                </div>
          </li>
       </ul>
```

I was wondering how to use slightly to achieve the above? I tried something below but it doesn't work:

```
<sly data-sly-resource="${'item' @ resourceType='components/header', cssClassName='toggleable-content'}"></sly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `section` markup is managed by the included resource (`components/header`) then you cannot do it directly. Indirectly, with AEM, you can pass a parameter (through [request attributes](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/experience-manager-htl/using/htl/block-statements.html?lang=en#request-attributes)) and retrieve it in the `components/header` model, then add the `section` conditionally (using `data-sly-unwrap` for example).

Or you re-organize your code and switch from resource inclusion to template calling and pass the parameter directly using [`data-sly-call`](https://github.com/adobe/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#22102-call).